# Finding the intersection of 2 ray normals

Tags: geometry

I have 2 rays, defined by a common point and a direction vector and I want to find the point at which the normals of the 2 rays intersect at a given distance along the normals and the distance along the rays these normals start at.

[image]

So in this system, A is the common point of the two rays, B and C are the direction vectors, and D and E are the length of the normal vectors.

I want to find the three ? points.

Comment: If you know `C`, `B`, `D` and `E` just find the intersection of `B` and `E` (solve for unknowns) to find the right `?`. Similarly do it for the left `?`. As for the center `?` find solutions for `D` and `E`.

Comment: I don't know how far along B the start of the E vector is, so I don't think that'll work?

Comment: Can you give me an example of how `B` is represented?

Comment: Sure, B is just a 2 element Vector, so {1, 2}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my idea

First, define a line that is parallel to the existing line, that is, through A oriented along vector B, but is offset by vector E.

Define a second line that is parallel to the existing line, that is, through A oriented alone vector C, but is offset by vector D.

Find the intersection of these two new lines, this should give you the topmost ? you are looking for.

Comment: I figure once that point is solved, the other two would be easier with trig relations to get all the lengths of the sides of the two inner triangles

Comment: Yeah, the middle point is the critical one, once that's found everything else falls into place. btw I'm just holding off giving accepted answer for a while to see if anyone else comes up with anything.